# how can i fix invalid column name in native query in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb

Good time

I have a problem with mapping my result set in entity manager in nativ query in java and I get an Invalid column name error. Please help me

entity class is :

```
package model.entity;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@LocalBean
@Stateful
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "TARAZ", schema = "SAB113")
public final class BallanceEntity implements Serializable {
   private Long id ;
   private String branchCode ;
   private String accountNumber ;
   private Integer dateTr ;
   private String commentPublic ;
   private  String obl ;
   private Long bed ;
   private Long bes ;
   private  String trType ;
   private String trComment ;
   public BallanceEntity() {
   }

   public BallanceEntity(Long id, String branchCode, String accountNumber,
   Integer dateTr,String co
                         String obl, Long bed, Long bes, String trType, String trComment) {
       this.id = id;
       this.branchCode = branchCode;
       this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
       this.dateTr = dateTr;
       this.commentPublic = commentPublic;
       this.obl = obl;
       this.bed = bed;
       this.bes = bes;
       this.trType = trType;
       this.trComment = trComment;
   }
  
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "NUMBER", 
   nullable = true, unique = tru
   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   
   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "BRANCH_CODE", columnDefinition = 
   "VARCHAR2(6)", nullable = true
   public String getBranchCode() {
       return branchCode;
   }
   
   public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
       this.branchCode = branchCode;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER",
   columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(20)", nullable = 
   public String getAccountNumber() {
       return accountNumber;
   }
   
   public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
       this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "DATE_TR", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(7)", nullable = true)
   public Integer getDateTr() {
       return dateTr;
   }
   
   public void setDateTr(Integer dateTr) {
       this.dateTr = dateTr;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "COMMENT_PUBLIC", 
   columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(32)", nullable = 
   public String getCommentPublic() {
       return commentPublic;
   }
   
   public void setCommentPublic(String commentPublic) {
       this.commentPublic = commentPublic;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "OBL", columnDefinition = "CHAR(10)", nullable = true)
   public String getObl() {
       return obl;
   }
   
   public void setObl(String obl) {
       this.obl = obl;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "BED", columnDefinition = "NUMBER", nullable = true)
   public Long getBed() {
       return bed;
   }
   
   public void setBed(Long bed) {
       this.bed = bed;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "BES", columnDefinition = "NUMBER", nullable = true)
   public Long getBes() {
       return bes;
   }
   
   public void setBes(Long bes) {
       this.bes = bes;
   }
    
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "TR_TYPE", columnDefinition = "CHAR(3)", nullable = true)
   public String getTrType() {
       return trType;
   }
   
   public void setTrType(String trType) {
       this.trType = trType;
   }
   
   @javax.persistence.Basic
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "TR_COMMENT", columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)", nullable =true)
   public String getTrComment() {
       return trComment;
   }
   
   public void setTrComment(String trComment) {
       this.trComment = trComment;
   }
 }
```

and native query is

```
package model.bl;
import model.entity.AccountBillEntity;
import model.entity.BallanceEntity;
import model.pattern.CDIBaseModel;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.List;

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class BallancRepMgr extends CDIBaseModel implements Serializable {


    @Transactional
    public List<BallanceEntity> selectKrsReport(Integer repDateFrom, Integer repDateTo,
                                                String branchCode, String ballanceType) throws   

        List<BallanceEntity> result = null;
    

        if (ballanceType.compareTo("1") == 0) {
          

       result = entityManager.createNativeQuery
    ("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER) as ID,BRANCH_CODE,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,OBL," 
    "       (CASE WHEN SUM(BED) + SUM (BES) > 0 THEN SUM(BED) + SUM(BES) ELSE 0 END) as BED ," +
    "       (CASE WHEN SUM(BED) + SUM(BES) <=0 THEN SUM(BED) + SUM(BES) ELSE 0 END ) as BES ," +
                            "       MAX(TR_COMMENT) as TR_COMMENT FROM TARAZ " +
                            "WHERE DATE_TR BETWEEN :repDateFrom AND :repDateTo " +
                            "GROUP BY BRANCH_CODE, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, OBL " +
                            "HAVING BRANCH_CODE=:branchCode", BallanceEntity.class)
                    .setParameter("branchCode", branchCode)
                    .setParameter("repDateFrom", repDateFrom)
                    .setParameter("repDateTo", repDateTo)
                    .getResultList();
        }

                  if (result.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("empty");


        return result;
    }

}
```

my error log is :

```
14:25:15,893 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) Invalid column name
14:25:15,900 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component BallancRepMgr for method public java.util.List model.bl.BallancRepMgr.selectKrsReport(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:246)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:618)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at model.bl.BallancRepMgr$$$view36.selectKrsReport(Unknown Source)
    at controller.BallanceRepCtrl.load(BallanceRepCtrl.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:157)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:265)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:126)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:490)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:211)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1395)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at model.bl.BallancRepMgr.selectKrsReport(BallancRepMgr.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInCallerTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:186)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:55)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:88)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.delegateInterception(EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 149 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:594)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getString(WrappedResultSet.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1746)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    ... 157 more

14:25:15,903 ERROR [core.BaseController] (default task-2) Error: Query Error ... 
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're telling Hibernate to hydrate the query results as a list of `BallanceEntity` objects, but that's not what the query is returning.

You have a few columns missing from your `SELECT` statement. See if it works after adding them in.

Or if you need to exclude those columns from the results, you can change the result class to `Object[]` instead of `BallanceEntity`.

Comment: when use select * ... all thing is corect but use the columns name i get invalid column name error ,Although the names of the fields are correct .

Comment: Ah okay. I updated my answer. Be sure you're selecting every column, otherwise Hibernate won't know how to hydrate the results into entity objects.

Comment: i can not cast object to BallanceEntity ,when i cast get empty result but Surely there is an answer to blindness

Answer (score 0):

Mention error specifically says, after returning results, while mapping to `BallanceEntity` from resultset, it is unable to resolve a column name which is been passed.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
```

Put a debugger at `getColumnIndex(...)` and see what was the column name that you get here before it throws that error.